# Spring Security pre-authentication - gives me a new session even though principal is unchanged

Tags: session, grails, spring-security

I have implemented a spring security preathentication filter in my Grails application in order to integrate with Tivoli Access Manager.

The filter getting called for every request in my web application - yet even though the filter returns the same principal as a previous request, it seems to create a new session. I have created a ApplicationListener to listen for authentication events and I can see a new AuthenticationSuccessEvent, with a new session id for each request.

This means all my session variables get cleared each request- which wouldn't be a big deal but it breaks the uploadr plugin.

When I turn debug logging on for my preauthentication filter I see that it thinks the principal has changed, even though it has not:

```
2015-03-04 11:34:57.769 foobar.TamAuthenticationFilter Checking secure context token: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken@f0666480: Principal: grails.plugin.springsecurity.userdetails.GrailsUser@3125618: Username: 66734; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_APPROVER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 87928D9E25D98DD3CCFAC5D67689E609; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_APPROVER
2015-03-04 11:34:57.770 foobar.TamAuthenticationFilter Pre-authenticated principal has changed to 66734 and will be reauthenticated
2015-03-04 11:34:57.770 foobar.TamAuthenticationFilter Invalidating existing session
2015-03-04 11:34:57.771 foobar.TamAuthenticationFilter preAuthenticatedPrincipal = 66734, trying to authenticate
```

How can I make spring security use the same session for each principal returned by the pre authentication filter, rather than create a new one for every request?

here is my filter:

```
package foobar

import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
import grails.util.Environment
import grails.util.Holders
import groovy.util.logging.Log4j

@Log4j
class TamAuthenticationFilter extends   AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {

java.lang.Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)
{
    "N/A"
}

java.lang.Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)
{
    Long staffId = getStaffIdFromTamHeader(request)
    if(!staffId)
        log.error "iv-user header not found"

    return staffId
}

/**
 * Get Staff ID from the ivUser Tamheader.
 * @param request
 * @return
 */
static public Long getStaffIdFromTamHeader(request) {
    return request.getHeader("iv-user")
}

}
```

LoggingSecurityEventListener:

```
 package foobar

 import groovy.util.logging.Log4j
 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
 import org.springframework.security.authentication.event.AbstractAuthenticationEvent


 @Log4j
 class LoggingSecurityEventListener implements
    ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {

    def username = event.authentication.principal
    def address = event.authentication.details.remoteAddress
    def sessionId = event.authentication.details.sessionId

    log.info "event=${event.class.simpleName} username=${username} remoteAddress=${address} sessionId=${sessionId}"

}

 }
```

resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
//
// grabs the user id from the tam headers 
//
tamAuthenticationFilter(TamAuthenticationFilter) {
    authenticationManager = ref('authenticationManager')
    checkForPrincipalChanges = true
}

tamAuthenticationProvider(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider) {
   preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService = ref('authenticationUserDetailsService')
}

//
// we do not want to redirect to the auth/login page since we are using tam
//
authenticationEntryPoint(Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint)

securityEventListener(LoggingSecurityEventListener)
}
```

config.groovy:

```
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['tamAuthenticationProvider']

 grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'strobe.auth.User'
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'strobe.auth.UserRole'
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'strobe.auth.Role'
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType="InterceptUrlMap"
 grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
                                            '/foobar/**':                   ['ROLE_USER']]
```

bootstrap.groovy:

```
 def init = { servletContext ->                   SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('tamAuthenticationFilter',
            SecurityFilterPosition.PRE_AUTH_FILTER.order + 10)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem- I was returning a Long from getPreauthenticatedPrincipal() which confuses spring security, as the method requiresAuthentication() in AbstractPreauthenticatedProcessingFilter has this line of code:

```
    if ((principal instanceof String) && currentUser.getName().equals(principal)) {
        return false;
    }
```

It expects the principal to be a String. Every time I returned a long it would reauthenticate and give me a new session.

I can't believe the solution was that simple and it took me 2 days to figure out!!!

Part of the problem I think is the scant documentation on preauthentication in spring and also the method signature of:

```
java.lang.Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request)
```

which doesn't clearly suggest a return type.